# Struggling to update class attribute in my Django form field widgets programmatically

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm having trouble looping through the fields I have in a form and updating the class attribute in the fields widgets. Here is my loop:

```
for field in form:
    try:
        field.widget.attrs['class'] += " invalid"
    except:
        pass
```

I cannot for the life me figure out why. I thought this would be the correct way to access the fields widgets.

Comment: What's the exact problem? To iterate or to update a class attribute?

Comment: Updating the class attribute

Comment: Why dont you print the exception and see, so me it looks like, the attribute dictionary does not have the key class, because what is happening is 
`field.widget.attr['class'] = filed.widget.attr['class'] + ' invalid' `
and since it doe not have the key class it fails there

Comment: Is the result class attributes which are not updated? Firstly remove 'except', we do not know if a compiler comes to the 'except'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for field in form:
    try:
        field.field.widget.attrs['class'] = (field.field.widget.attr.get('class') or '') + " invalid"
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

The trouble with
    `field.field.widget.attrs['class'] += " invalid"`
is that it will throw a key error if the key `class` is not already present because it does something like
    `field.field.widget.attrs['class'] = field.field.widget.attrs['class'] +  " invalid"`

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. In the end it was:

field.field.widget.attrs['class'] = (field.field.widget.attr.get('class') or '') + " invalid"

Comment: Cool, I would suggest you always print you exceptions, so that you can see what the error is :)